# Where do I add a systemcall to the linux Kernel source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to add a new helloworld system call to a new version of the Linux Ubuntu kernel.  I have been looking through the web but I cannot find a consistent example to show me what files I will have to modify to enable a helloworld system call to be added to the kernel.

I have tried many and compile error have occurred.
I know how to compile the kernel, but I just don't know where I add my c program system call, and where I add this call to the system call table and anything else I have to do.

I am working on the newest Linux Ubuntu kernel.

I compiled the kernel with a new system call introduced, a simple call called mycall, now I am getting compile errors within the header file of my application that will test the call, below is my header file

```
#include<linux/unistd.h>

#define __NR_mycall 317

_syscall1(long, mycall, int, i)
```

This is the syntax error I am getting

```
stef@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o testmycall testmycall.c
In file included from testmycall.c:3:
testmycall.h:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mycall’
testmycall.h:7: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘i’
testmycall.c: In function ‘_syscall1’:
testmycall.c:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
testmycall.h:7: error: parameter name omitted
testmycall.h:7: error: parameter name omitted
testmycall.c:11: error: expected ‘{’ at end of in
```

I got a lot of help from the below link from Nikolai N Fetissov

Comment: What did you try?  What compile errors occurred?  [Is this still homework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977675/i-need-information-on-system-calls-and-understanding-them) - please tag as such if so.  The article linked in the answer to that question is good for general principles, I think, although a bit out-of-date, as kernel development tends to moves rapidly.  A tip: things that used to be in `arch/i386` in older versions are now in `arch/x86` (the 32-bit and 64-bit stuff got merged).  [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/linux) is useful for searching either current or old kernel versions.

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/

Comment: i got rid of the compile error by accident , i will try again and if it comes up i will edit the post with the error, ok cheers for the advice on arch/x86, will be trying this now, will be back in about an hour when i get all this done and the compiling aswell!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '_syscall1' macro that you are using is obsolete. Use syscall(2) instead.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define __NR_mysyscall     317

int main(void)
{
        long return_value;

        return_value = syscall(__NR_syscall);

        printf("The return value is %ld.\n", return_value);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

2nd chapter, Operating system principles- galvin.
Straight forward procedure.

Comment: Please do not include a 'signature' when posting; your user box already shows your name. Also... I'm not sure what this answer means.